# Grant select privilege to rows with condition

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

how to grant a read privilege to all information included in a view DRVADM
except the rows where a date of birth is not empty to a user?

Comment: This is not possible in mysql. That row or cell-level security is something built from the ground up in such platforms as Accumulo.

Comment: I have been asked for a school lab to perform this function, is it ok if i create a seperate table with the value where date of birth is null and give select privilege on that new table instead?

Comment: Are you truly talking about select privileges at the user level (security), or are you merely talking about result set tweaking?

Comment: @Drew yeah i am talking about user level privileges but i have to execute this condition somehow, so i was talking about creating a new table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
drop table if exists variousRights;
create table variousRights
(   -- whitelist table of various privileges
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    rightType varchar(100) not null,
    username varchar(100) not null
);

-- sample data below. For this exercise, all we care about is 'seeNullBirthDateRows'
-- but other data is inserted to ferret out troubles with strategy (too many rows returned)
insert variousRights (rightType,userName) values
('seeNullBirthDateRows','root@localhost'),
('seeNullBirthDateRows','sam@localhost'),
('seeSecretIDs','root@localhost'),
('insertThing101','root@localhost');

drop table if exists employees;
create table employees
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    empName varchar(100) not null,
    birthDate date null
);

-- sample data inserted. One has a null for birthDate (empty as you say in the question)
insert employees(empName,birthDate) values
('John Smith',null),
('Sally Higgins','2016-02-07'),
('John Smith','2010-01-27');
```

The query:

```
select id,empName,birthDate 
from employees
where birthDate is not null
union
select e.id,e.empName,e.birthDate 
from employees e
cross join (select id from variousRights where rightType='seeNullBirthDateRows' and userName=current_user()) vr
where e.birthDate is null;
```

The query relies on a Cross Join and a union. As for the union, the first part will be the same for all users: all rows from `employees` with a non-null birthDay. The second part of the union will return the nulls for users so privileged in the `variousRights` table where you dream up your privileges.

Naturally the above query can be plopped into a view.

See the mysql manual page for the [CURRENT_USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) function.

As for the `cross join`, think of it this way. It is a cartesian product. But the table joined on (alias `vr`) will either have 1 row or 0 coming back. That is what determines whether or not privileged users see the null birthDate rows.

Note: The above has been tested. Seems to work fine.