# SQL is it possible to add a WHERE clause to a GRANT SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-grant

I would like to be able to grant read privileges to all information within a view except the rows where DOB is not empty (i.e. user can only read row where DOB is null). Is this possible? An example (which doesn't work that I would like to work) is:

```
GRANT SELECT ON DRVADM WHERE DOB IS NULL TO user_2;
```

Thanks

Comment: why don't you add the condition to the view itself? or make one more view with dob is null condition

Comment: this is for a homework task unfortunately, and it has to use the DRVADM view, which already has a different user with different read privileges

Comment: apologies, its simply local sql executed through Ubuntu terminal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql GRANT + WHERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693727/mysql-grant-where)

Comment: Ah yes, I think it is, sorry I couldn't find anything like that after searching. Guess we were set an impossible homework task

Comment: This looks so very similar to the following question by a different user 30 minutes before http://stackoverflow.com/q/37494907

Comment: @Drew haha so it is, I assume that's someone in the same course as me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I assume you are using `mysql` (to confirm that, post the commands you use to connect to the database from your terminal session).
2. You can not `GRANT` based on rows, only on the level of columns/tables. There is no `WHERE` clause to a `GRANT SELECT` statement in [mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html)
3. You could consider creating a `VIEW` with only **selected rows** (the ones he has to see). Then grant user access to this `VIEW` (=to **all its rows**)

Comment: Yes, using mysql in terminal, connected with  
    use database1;  
And as this is a homework task (as mentioned above) I cannot unfortunately create a new view, i have to use DRVADM which has another use allowed to read everything

Comment: If your task is literally 'to grant read privileges to all information within a view except some rows'  then I do not see a possible solution with `mysql` (due to the reason explained in the second item of my answer).

Comment: That is literally that part of the task, so thank you anyway, I'll have to speak to our tutor about it. It is as follows (i did 3, but 4 is related to this question): (3) The script grants a read privilege to all information included a view DRVADM to user_1. (4) Next, the script grants a read privilege to all information included in a view DRVADM except the rows where a date of birth is not empty to user_2

Comment: If you look at the answer I posted to your class mate (the comment under your question) ... I could modify that to hide (blank out) but still show the row. Blanking out at the cell level. All it takes is a little ingenuity to solve your particular problem. Because #3 above inadequately solves the problem for all users.